# How to set initial selections of controls in a MS access report on its load?

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Access 2007 report which is based on a query that has some parameters that can be modified by selecting values in listboxes that are in the header of the report. The flow is as follows:

- A user selects parameters in listboxes
- A user clicks "generate" button. I have an OnClick event attached to it, which goes through all the listboxes, picks up their selections, puts together an SQL statement and sets it as source for the underlying MS Access query.
- The only way I could find to properly refresh the report was to first do `Me.Requery` and then close and reopen the report. Just `Me.Requery` was not enough.
- After the report is reopened, all the selections in the listboxes are lost. But I have them saved in a variable and I would be able to set them back, but I cannot find a suitable event.

I tried Report `Load`, `Open`, `Current` events - none of them worked. For `Current` event, I see that the selection gets set but then is deselected immediately. Could anybody suggest me what other event could I try or maybe a slight different approach all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me this one could be easier by giving the user a form with those list box controls, let her make her selections there, and then pass the selection criteria as the  WhereCondition parameter to [DoCmd.OpenReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238032%28office.12%29.aspx).

From that page, the WhereCondition parameter is "*A string expression that's a valid SQL WHERE clause without the word WHERE*".

Comment: Agree, but it makes the interface clumsy - you need to select something here, then see the results there.. I'd like to have everything as easy to use as possible otherwise my "users" will simply refrain from using the DB (they have such an option - just to stick with good old excel list)

Comment: What about having a form (perhaps a continuous one) containing BOTH the parameters AND the parameterized query's results? That might be the best UI for VIEWING data on screen. And then you could create a report (and add a Print button to the form) if your users want a printout that looks nicer than direct printout of the form itself.